# Issu while Installing Intel Parallel studio in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, intel, development

I am trying to install Intel Parallel studio in Ubuntu 14.04. I type this commands in bash:

```
sudo su

chmod -R 777 ./

./install.sh
```

and i get this error:

```
./install.sh: 248: .: Can't open /tmp/intel.pset.strings.root.noosh-X455LD
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can progress with the install?

Comment: please be more specific: which version / edition of parallel studio? What kind of installation files? Where did you get them from? Be careful running command in a root shell - you may damage your system

Comment: Hi its intel parallel studio 2015-update 1. For installation I should run install_GUI.sh or install.sh but when I try to run it I have got that error! And either I am super user or not, the error is the same. I also have another question when i installed linux 12 or 14 in my laptop i saw its Linux 3 but I remember that in my previous system when i installed, it was linux 2! Is it important in installation?

Answer (score 0):

Make a directory and change into it:

```
mkdir $HOME/ips2015
cd $HOME/ips2015
```

Do a fresh download of installation file(s) to this directory. If necessary extract installation files from archiv. Change to the directory where `install_GUI.sh` is in and execute:

```
chmod 0755 install_GUI.sh
sudo ./install_GUI.sh
```

is that fails post the error messages and the output of the commando

```
find $HOME/ips2015 -ls
```